# Variable defined in a for loop not visible by subfunction (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I thought I understood the "closure" behaviour of Javascript, and to prevent the most complex problem of this I usually use "let" instead of "var" in all my code. But it seems it is not enough in this case.

I defined a variable in a `for` loop (called `i` here for more conveniance). In my loop, I call a function, which has not any parameters, defined somewhere outside the loop, which use this very variable. But it seems that it cannot reach the value of `i`, even if it is present in the loop scope.

I know that if I defined the variable `i` outside the loop, or if I remove `let` in the `for` line, it would solve my problem. The question is : why does not my function know the value of `i`?

```js
function printiValue()
{
    alert(i);
}

let table = [1,2,3];
for (let i of table)
{
    printiValue();
}
```

Comment: That's not how variables work.  You need to use parameters.

Comment: Yes, i think I will definitely do that. I just wonder why this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "let" itself should be clear enough:

"let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope."

Given that definition, the let i in your for loop means its scope is within that for loop, but not within functions called within that loop, unless they are passed it as a parameter.

Run this if you don't believe/understand:

```
function b() {
  console.log(typeof i);
}

function a() {
    let i = 10;
    b();
}

a();
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeVPPB

Comment: But does not a function have access to variables defined in the block where it is used?

Comment: @Flunec No, it has access to variables defined in the block where it is defined, not where it is used. `alert(i);` is lexically outside the for loop so `i` is not in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Because `let` is just block wide.

You have to declare your variable `i` before the loop in this case but a `forEach` loop would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

To make your code work try this:

```
function printiValue(param)
{
    alert(param);
}

let table = [1,2,3];
for (let i of table)
{
    printiValue(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared outside the scope of your for loop, so it has no access to the `i` value You're also using a `for of` loop, which is for an object, not an array, you should use a regular `for` loop. You can either

declare a variable and increment it in the loop

```js
let i = 0;
function printiValue()
{
    alert(i);
}

let table = [1,2,3];
for (let j = 0; j < table.length; j++)
{
    printiValue();
    i++;
}
```

or pass in i as a parameter:

```js
function printiValue(i)
{
    alert(i);
}

let table = [1,2,3];
for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
{
    printiValue(i);
}
```

Hope that helps!